# Access query recordset result output to word shows special characters

Tags: ms-access, ms-word, vba, ms-access-2010

Problem Description:
I am using Microsoft Access Plus 2010, with below code to export the result of query to Word table. However, there are all kinds of special characters exported if the record is over 255 characters.

Below are the query, VBA etc.

**Query name**: Qa

**Query function**: select field from Ta

**VBA**:

```
Dim qbf As QueryDef
Dim dabase As Database
Set dabase = CurrentDb
Set qdf = dbase.QueryDefs(Qa)
Dim results As Recordset
Dim flds As String
Set results = qdf.OpenRecordset()
While (Not results.EOF)
    doc.addRecord results
    results.MoveNext
Wend
qdf.Close

Public Sub addRecord(pubRecordSet As Recordset)
flds = pubRecordSet.Fields("fieldname")
    mTable.cell(1, 1).range.InsertAfter (flds)
...
End Sub
```

Where 'mTable' is a Word table object, 'fieldname' is the name of the field to be exported to Word Table.
This VBA in general works fine when the length of flds is less than 255, however, it throws a lot of special characters in the Table cell if the length exceeds 255.

Example on special characters exported to Word table cell:

```
 退D瞻껙皿  Ƭ" "  ᬈ௩Hȷ⫗ 鋨D૝૝ｨ௨瞻껥皿௲Ǭ" "Tೕ ŮԱ ࿨ซ鐌D
```

I checked the limitation of MS Access from [link here](http://www.databasezone.com/techdocs/acclimit.html). It mentions the recordset of query is 1GB, which my data is way less (~255 characters). Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Things to check: 1) if you open the query in datasheet view, is the text for the affected records shown correctly? 2) add `Debug.Print flds` after setting it, and check the output in the Direct window (Ctrl+G).

Comment: And: what datatype is `flds`? Should be String

Comment: The type of flds is string. I did the Debug.Print, and found that the string was truncated by "Set results = qdf.OpenRecordset()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think they are being truncated or corrupted almost certainly to do with one of the reasons listed here : http://allenbrowne.com/ser-63.html

By definition if they are over 255 character long they will be interpreted as Memo or Long text (Same definition - Memo is the older name of the data type).

Comment: Yes, I hit this bug 'Concatenated fields yield garbage in recordset' http://allenbrowne.com/bug-16.html. It works with the 'union all StructureOnly table' work around. Thank you very much!